# String Split On CSV asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, reader

`A574A02211     S193FDRA3     20141023S17337     WAN HAI 307`

`A024A13787     S1023F                S1023F     WAN HAI 316`

`A574A02181     S187FDRA3     20141024S17337     WAN HAI 307`

i have a csv file like that   as above but,

```
nextCellPlace = FindNextCell(data[dataCounter], spacePlace);
spacePlace = data[dataCounter].IndexOf(" ", nextCellPlace);
arrivalShip.Add(GetCellValue(data[dataCounter], nextCellPlace, spacePlace));enter
```

im using this code get a third column data, but i wantto slipt front date data  and string data, like that this

`A574A02211,S193FDRA3,20141023,S17337,WAN HAI 307`

if met at no date data i wantto write down NULL then goto continue get second data

like that this

```
A574A02211,S193FDRA3,20141023,S17337,WAN HAI 307
```

`A024A13787,S1023F,NULLDATE,S1023F,WAN HAI 316`

`A574A02181,S187FDRA3,20141024,S17337,WAN HAI 307`

Comment: If data is in fixed width format then instead of `split` use `substring` to get each value and then use `length` to check for date data. [SubString on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few cases that makes a simple `.Split(' ')` not work: blank values and values containing spaces. How about defining an array of indexes where you want to split your data, then run a set of substring operations to split it the way you want? This will also allow you to split in the middle of words such as `20141023S17337` => `20141023`, `S17337`.

```
var input = @"A574A02211     S193FDRA3     20141023S17337     WAN HAI 307
A024A13787     S1023F                S1023F     WAN HAI 316
A574A02181     S187FDRA3     20141024S17337     WAN HAI 307";

var positionsToSplitOn = new int [] { 0, 15, 29, 37, 48 };

var lines = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var line in input.Split('\n'))
{
    var columnValues = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < positionsToSplitOn.Length - 1; ++i)
    {
        columnValues.Add(line.Substring(positionsToSplitOn[i], positionsToSplitOn[i + 1] - positionsToSplitOn[i]).Trim());
    }
    columnValues.Add(line.Substring(positionsToSplitOn[positionsToSplitOn.Length - 1]).Trim());
    lines.Add(columnValues);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get lines of your csv file using the following.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToCSVFile);
```

Then, you can split each line and analyse its containing.

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
   string[] fields = lines[i].Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

   // analyse the fields
}
```

Not that the number of elements in fields can be considered as a hist that whether the line contains Data or not.

Comment: Are you sure about split(" "   ?  not split "," ?

Comment: i dont use split for ',' i just seperate this data == 20141023S17337 like that this 20141023,S17337, if front no date like that this nulldate, S17337